# ¿Cómo hacer una doble consulta?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy tratando de hacer una doble consulta a una tabla pero con una condición.
si la variable del WHERE está vacia que muestre todo, de otro modo que muestre lo consultado.
Así es como lo tengo y no funciona:

```html
 $buscar = mysqli_real_escape_string($connex, $_POST['buscar']);

if($buscar == null){
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM item  order by id DESC";
 }else{
  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE  item='$buscar' order by id DESC";
  }
```

Comment: Creo que tu condicion esta al revez.

Comment: lo acomodé y sigue igual

Comment: Cual es el problema, te marca algun error?

Comment: A que te refieres que no funciona? Salta error? No te devuelve los resultados que esperabas?

Comment: Pon el código donde ejecutas la consulta sql

Comment: Estoy haciendo la consulta por medio de ajax y debo presionar el bar space para que me muestre los resultados

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debe de haber una funcion en mysql que si existe lo pueda tomar, del caso contrario tome su valor con la que entra.

```
SELECT *
FROM tabla 
WHERE (item ISNULL('$item', '$item') )
```

intenta de esta forma..

o

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM item ";
if(isset($buscar)){
    $SQL .=" WHERE  item='$buscar'";
}
$SQL .=" order by id DESC";
```

Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: Estoy haciendo la consulta por medio de ajax y debo presionar el bar space para que me muestre los resultados

Comment: ok, pero lo que necesitas es concatenar la consulta. prueba lo del caso contrario agrega mas información a tu pregunta.